# Can't ping/ssh Openstack VM internal instance from controller

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, private-cloud

I have a working single-node centos Openstack instance which is working in most regards nicely, except for one problem which has me tearing my hair out.

The problem is this: when I create new VM instances, I am unable to ping/ssh them from the controller machine.  So, when the VM comes up on the 10.0.1.x network, I cannot directly access it from the controller.  I can access the machine from the Horizon Console app - which baffles me, since horizon is running on the controller.  If I add a floating IP to the machine, I can access it no problem both from the controller as well as from any system on the LAN.

I have already confirmed that security groups are properly set up and opened to allow access to both ssh and icmp.  Here's the security group settings:

```
ALLOW IPv6 to ::/0
ALLOW IPv4 to 0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW IPv4 from default
ALLOW IPv6 from default
ALLOW IPv4 22/tcp from 0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW IPv4 icmp from 0.0.0.0/0
```

And here's various other settings which might help identify the problem:

```
br-ex: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.200  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::dacb:8aff:fea4:471  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether d8:cb:8a:a4:04:71  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 418591  bytes 66744430 (63.6 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 51  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 217891  bytes 165063129 (157.4 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


[liz@openstack-controlle ~(keystone_admin)]$ neutron net-list
+--------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id                                   | name          | subnets                                             |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| a1ab7093-2884-4032-8511-003e89fcb81e | external      | c184b9ef-f16d-4aad-9c7b-5d2f5e49ce58 192.168.1.0/24 |
| bb3da742-1223-4859-83f1-d03bda84ff2d | intenal-saidi | 160b1f41-de0a-40e0-9d3d-9a6630347e0e 10.0.1.0/24    |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+

[liz@openstack-controlle ~(keystone_admin)]$ neutron router-list
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+
| id                                   | name         | external_gateway_info                                                                                                                                                                     | distributed | ha    |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+
| 9cd5d292-a7bb-4dcf-969d-f174e397b949 | router-saidi | {"network_id": "a1ab7093-2884-4032-8511-003e89fcb81e", "enable_snat": true, "external_fixed_ips": [{"subnet_id": "c184b9ef-f16d-4aad-9c7b-5d2f5e49ce58", "ip_address": "192.168.1.201"}]} | False       | False |
+--------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Jesus! No one? I'm in trouble too..

Comment: I've the same error. I've opened these posts:https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/119783/no-pingssh-to-openstack-instance-from-neutron-gateway0/ and maybe the issue is done from this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283357/openstack-neutron-gateway-error-could-not-add-network-device-eno2-to-ofproto