# openstack neutron-gateway - error: "could not add network device eno2 to ofproto (Device or resource busy)"

Tags: openstack-neutron, juju

I performed a cluster node installation using this guide [OpenStack Charms Deployment Guide].(https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-maas.html), where the type of network is a Flat network and the components used are:

- Maas
- Juju
- Openstack

My lab is composed by following devices:

```
1 IBM System 3540 M4 Maas (500GB HDD - 8GB RAM - 1 Nic)
1 IBM System 3540 M4 Juju (500GB HDD - 8GB RAM -1 Nic)
4 IBM System 3540 M4 Openstack (500GBx2 HDD - 16GB RAM - 2 Nic)
1 Palo Alto Network Firewall
Public Network 10.20.81.0/24 - Private Network 10.0.0.0/24

Maas: 10.20.81.1
Juju: 10.20.81.2
Openstack 10.20.81.21-24
Gateway 10.20.81.254
Instance: 10.0.0.9 - 10.20.81.215 (floating)
```

network plan

```
10.20.81.0/24     
                          +-------------+
                              Firewall
                            10.20.81.254
                          +-------------+
                                 | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
                              Switch 
      vlan81              vlan81                  vlan81
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
        |                   |                   || | | |
+--------------+     +------------+        +------------------+
|Maas+Juju           |Juju Gui|            |Openstack
|10.20.81.1          |10.20.81.2           |10.20.81.21-24
+--------------+     +-------------+       +------------------+
                                                     |
                                +--------------------------------------------+
                                Private Subnet-1           Public Subnet-2
                                 10.0.0.0/24                10.20.81.0/24
                                 +---+----+--+              +----+------+
                                 |    |        +----+            |
                                 |    |        |    |            |
                                 |    +--------+ VR +-------------+
                                 |             |    |
                                 +--+-+        +----+
                                 |    |
                                 | VM |
                                 | .9 |
                                 |    |
                                 +----+
```

On my lab, the nodes for Openstack present two eth interface, the first one (eno2) the single external network used as floating IP, then the other one (eno3) for the private network.

On Juju gui I've that:

```
neutron-gateway:
    bridge-mappings:         physnet1:br-ex
    data-port:               br-ex:eno2
neutron-api:
    flat-network-providers:  physnet1
```

I've opened this post https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/119783/no-route-to-instance-ssh-and-ping-no-route-to-host/ to resolve the problem about the Ping and Ssh connection to my instance, but during same check I've seen this issue on neutron-gateway:

```
error: "could not add network device eno2 to ofproto (Device or resource busy)"
```

Maybe that is the cause of my first issue, but I don't understand how I can fix it.

```
    $:juju ssh neutron-gateway/0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Mar 19 16:07:19 UTC 2019

  System load:  0.64               Processes:              409
  Usage of /:   5.7% of 273.00GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 13%                IP address for lxdbr0:  10.122.135.1
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for br-eno2: 10.20.81.21

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

3 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
ovs-vsctl show output

ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ sudo ovs-vsctl show
6f8542aa-45d7-409d-8787-8983f3c643eb
    Manager "ptcp:6640:127.0.0.1"
        is_connected: true
    Bridge br-ex
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port "eno2"
            Interface "eno2"
                error: "could not add network device eno2 to ofproto (Device or resource busy)"
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
        Port phy-br-ex
            Interface phy-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=int-br-ex}
    Bridge br-tun
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port patch-int
            Interface patch-int
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-tun}
        Port br-tun
            Interface br-tun
                type: internal
        Port "gre-0a145118"
            Interface "gre-0a145118"
                type: gre
                options: {df_default="true", in_key=flow, local_ip="10.20.81.21", out_key=flow, remote_ip="10.20.81.24"}
    Bridge br-int
        Controller "tcp:127.0.0.1:6633"
            is_connected: true
        fail_mode: secure
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port patch-tun
            Interface patch-tun
                type: patch
                options: {peer=patch-int}
        Port "tapb0b04b07-8f"
            tag: 2
            Interface "tapb0b04b07-8f"
        Port int-br-ex
            Interface int-br-ex
                type: patch
                options: {peer=phy-br-ex}
        Port "tap2354468c-88"
            tag: 4
            Interface "tap2354468c-88"
        Port "tap6d2b2fe0-47"
            tag: 4
            Interface "tap6d2b2fe0-47"
    ovs_version: "2.10.0"
```

juju status

```
$:juju status

Model      Controller             Cloud/Region  Version  SLA          Timestamp
openstack  maas-cloud-controller  maas-cloud    2.5.1    unsupported  22:10:17Z

App                    Version       Status  Scale  Charm                  Store       Rev  OS      Notes
ceph-mon               13.2.4+dfsg1  active      3  ceph-mon               jujucharms   31  ubuntu  
ceph-osd               13.2.4+dfsg1  active      3  ceph-osd               jujucharms  273  ubuntu  
ceph-radosgw           13.2.4+dfsg1  active      1  ceph-radosgw           jujucharms  262  ubuntu  
cinder                 13.0.2        active      1  cinder                 jujucharms  276  ubuntu  
cinder-ceph            13.0.2        active      1  cinder-ceph            jujucharms  238  ubuntu  
glance                 17.0.0        active      1  glance                 jujucharms  271  ubuntu  
keystone               14.0.1        active      1  keystone               jujucharms  288  ubuntu  
mysql                  5.7.20-29.24  active      1  percona-cluster        jujucharms  272  ubuntu  
neutron-api            13.0.2        active      1  neutron-api            jujucharms  266  ubuntu  
neutron-gateway        13.0.2        active      1  neutron-gateway        jujucharms  256  ubuntu  
neutron-openvswitch    13.0.2        active      3  neutron-openvswitch    jujucharms  255  ubuntu  
nova-cloud-controller  18.0.3        active      1  nova-cloud-controller  jujucharms  316  ubuntu  
nova-compute           18.0.3        active      3  nova-compute           jujucharms  290  ubuntu  
ntp                    3.2           active      4  ntp                    jujucharms   31  ubuntu  
openstack-dashboard    14.0.1        active      1  openstack-dashboard    jujucharms  271  ubuntu  
rabbitmq-server        3.6.10        active      1  rabbitmq-server        jujucharms   82  ubuntu  

Unit                      Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports                       Message
ceph-mon/0                active    idle   1/lxd/0  10.20.81.4                                  Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-mon/1                active    idle   2/lxd/0  10.20.81.8                                  Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-mon/2*               active    idle   3/lxd/0  10.20.81.5                                  Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-osd/0                active    idle   1        10.20.81.23                                 Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-osd/1                active    idle   2        10.20.81.22                                 Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-osd/2*               active    idle   3        10.20.81.24                                 Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-radosgw/0*           active    idle   0/lxd/0  10.20.81.15     80/tcp                      Unit is ready
cinder/0*                 active    idle   1/lxd/1  10.20.81.18     8776/tcp                    Unit is ready
  cinder-ceph/0*          active    idle            10.20.81.18                                 Unit is ready
glance/0*                 active    idle   2/lxd/1  10.20.81.6      9292/tcp                    Unit is ready
keystone/0*               active    idle   3/lxd/1  10.20.81.20     5000/tcp                    Unit is ready
mysql/0*                  active    idle   0/lxd/1  10.20.81.17     3306/tcp                    Unit is ready
neutron-api/0*            active    idle   1/lxd/2  10.20.81.7      9696/tcp                    Unit is ready
neutron-gateway/0*        active    idle   0        10.20.81.21                                 Unit is ready
  ntp/0*                  active    idle            10.20.81.21     123/udp                     chrony: Ready
nova-cloud-controller/0*  active    idle   2/lxd/2  10.20.81.3      8774/tcp,8775/tcp,8778/tcp  Unit is ready
nova-compute/0            active    idle   1        10.20.81.23                                 Unit is ready
  neutron-openvswitch/1   active    idle            10.20.81.23                                 Unit is ready
  ntp/2                   active    idle            10.20.81.23     123/udp                     chrony: Ready
nova-compute/1            active    idle   2        10.20.81.22                                 Unit is ready
  neutron-openvswitch/2   active    idle            10.20.81.22                                 Unit is ready
  ntp/3                   active    idle            10.20.81.22     123/udp                     chrony: Ready
nova-compute/2*           active    idle   3        10.20.81.24                                 Unit is ready
  neutron-openvswitch/0*  active    idle            10.20.81.24                                 Unit is ready
  ntp/1                   active    idle            10.20.81.24     123/udp                     chrony: Ready
openstack-dashboard/0*    active    idle   3/lxd/2  10.20.81.19     80/tcp,443/tcp              Unit is ready
rabbitmq-server/0*        active    idle   0/lxd/2  10.20.81.16     5672/tcp                    Unit is ready

Machine  State    DNS          Inst id              Series  AZ         Message
0        started  10.20.81.21  nbe8q3               bionic  Openstack  Deployed
0/lxd/0  started  10.20.81.15  juju-26461e-0-lxd-0  bionic  Openstack  Container started
0/lxd/1  started  10.20.81.17  juju-26461e-0-lxd-1  bionic  Openstack  Container started
0/lxd/2  started  10.20.81.16  juju-26461e-0-lxd-2  bionic  Openstack  Container started
1        started  10.20.81.23  pdnc7c               bionic  Openstack  Deployed
1/lxd/0  started  10.20.81.4   juju-26461e-1-lxd-0  bionic  Openstack  Container started
1/lxd/1  started  10.20.81.18  juju-26461e-1-lxd-1  bionic  Openstack  Container started
1/lxd/2  started  10.20.81.7   juju-26461e-1-lxd-2  bionic  Openstack  Container started
2        started  10.20.81.22  yxkyet               bionic  Openstack  Deployed
2/lxd/0  started  10.20.81.8   juju-26461e-2-lxd-0  bionic  Openstack  Container started
2/lxd/1  started  10.20.81.6   juju-26461e-2-lxd-1  bionic  Openstack  Container started
2/lxd/2  started  10.20.81.3   juju-26461e-2-lxd-2  bionic  Openstack  Container started
3        started  10.20.81.24  bgqsdy               bionic  Openstack  Deployed
3/lxd/0  started  10.20.81.5   juju-26461e-3-lxd-0  bionic  Openstack  Container started
3/lxd/1  started  10.20.81.20  juju-26461e-3-lxd-1  bionic  Openstack  Container started
3/lxd/2  started  10.20.81.19  juju-26461e-3-lxd-2  bionic  Openstack  Container started
iptables
```

Any suggestions please. I am still unable to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update 26/03/19:**

On Juju gui I've that:

```
neutron-gateway:
    bridge-mappings:         physnet1:br-ex
    data-port:               br-ex:eno2
neutron-api:
    flat-network-providers:  physnet1
```

Before to make the deploy of Openstack I've changed data-port from br-ex:eno2 to br-ex:eno3

```
neutron-gateway:
    bridge-mappings:         physnet1:br-ex
    data-port:               br-ex:eno3
```

The issue on eno2 is been resolved but the ping to instance is still present.